# How to show a fragment from another fragment?

Tags: android-fragments

I have used multiple fragment with fragment activity. When I click a button in one fragment, it should show another fragment. I don't know how to achieve this. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this through the Activity class like this.
Call a previously written activity class method from the fragment class on a particular event.

```
 __________________
| ParentActivity   |
|__________________|           _______________   
|                  |--------->| FrgamentA     |
|placeNewFragment()|          |_______________|
|__________________|          |               |
                              | // code here  |
                              |_______________|

 ParentActivity parent = (ParentActivity)getActivity();
 parent.placeNewFragment();
```